# Rails 4, Passenger, and Apache virtual host with asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, jquery-ui, passenger

I have a Rails 4 app that includes `gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '>= 5.0.0'` in the Gemfile.  I have managed to deploy this app to an Apache virtual host using Passenger.  My app is served from `http://server.com/myapp`  All is well except when I use the JQuery UI indeterminate progress bar, the animated GIF cannot be found so it appears as a blank gray box.

I have determined the problem is almost exactly as stated in [Dynatree unable to find assets in rails production on multi-virtual host apache install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906513/dynatree-unable-to-find-assets-in-rails-production-on-multi-virtual-host-apache)

Basically, the app is looking in `http://server.com/assets/jquery-ui/animated-overlay-xxx.gif` instead of `http://server.com/myapp/assets/jquery-ui/animated-overlay-xxx.gif`

How and where do I inject the `/myapp/` snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  In /config/environments/production.rb I did `config.relative_url_root = "/myapp"`  See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#deploy-to-a-subdirectory-relative-url-root